# Dropdown menu li:hover stops working and have to click to open submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a responsive dropdown menu with 4 buttons and one of them opens a submenu (portfolio). It works great, except that when I click the 'portafolio' button (which shouldn't be clicked because it uses a hover function) it closes the submenu and it won't open or close until I click on that button again. As I said it shouldn't be clicked but it's a mistake that can happen.

```js
$(document).ready(main);
 
var contador = 1;
 
function main () {
 $('.bt-menu').click(function(){
  if (contador == 1) {
   $('nav').animate({
    left: '0'
   });
   contador = 0;
  } else {
   contador = 1;
   $('nav').animate({
    left: '-100%'
   });
  }
 });
 
 // Mostramos y ocultamos submenus
 $('.submenu').click(function(){
  $(this).children('.children').slideToggle();
 });
}
```

```css
* {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu_bar {
 display:none;
}

header {
 width:100%;
}

header nav {
 z-index:1000;
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

header nav ul {
 list-style:none;
}

header nav ul li {
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
}

header nav ul li a {
 color:white;
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:20px 20px 10px 20px;
}

header nav ul li:nth-child(3n+3) a {  
  color: #999;
}

header nav ul li .caret {
 position:relative;
 top:3px;
 margin-left:10px;
 margin-right:0;
}

header nav ul li:hover .children {
 display:block;
}

header nav ul li .children {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 width: 200%;
 z-index: 1000;
 text-align: left;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 letter-spacing: 0;
}

header nav ul li .children li {
 display:block;
 overflow:hidden;
 border-bottom:1px solid #E6E6E6;
 min-width:50%;
}

header nav ul li .children li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;

}
header nav ul li .children li:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
}

header nav ul li .children li a {
 display:block;
 color:#111;
 padding:15px 25px;
}

header nav ul li .children li a:hover {
 background-color:#E6E6E6;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 body {
  padding-top:40px;
 }
 
 .menu_bar {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  background:black;
  z-index:1100;
  background:green;
 }
 
 .menu_bar .menu-logo {
  display:block;
  padding:20px 20px 10px 20px;
  color:white;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
  width:80%;
  font-size:24pt;
  letter-spacing:-2pt;
 }
 
 .menu_bar .bt-menu{
  display:block;
  padding:20px 20px 10px 20px;
  color:white;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size:25px;
  text-decoration:none;
  float:right;
  width:20%
 }
 
 .menu_bar span {
  float:right;
  font-size:30px;
  position:relative;
 }
 
 header nav {
  width:85%;
  height:calc(100% - 67px);
  position:fixed;
  right:100%;
  margin:0;
  overflow:scroll;
  background:black;
 }
 
 header nav ul li {
  display:block;
  border-bottom:1px solid #111;
 }
 
 header nav ul li a {
  display:block;
 }
 
 header nav ul li .children {
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
 }
 
 header nav ul li .children li {
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-bottom:1px solid #E6E6E6;
  min-width:100%;
 }

 header nav ul li .children li:nth-child(odd) {
     float: none;

 }
 header nav ul li .children li:nth-child(even) {
     float: none;
 }
 
 header nav ul li:hover .children {
  display:none;
 }
 
 header nav ul li .children li a {
  margin-left:;
 }
 
 header nav ul li .caret {
  float:right;
 }
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="header-logo">
    <div id="logo1"><a href="index.html" target="_self">ARMANDO</a></div>
    <div id="logo2"><a href="index.html" target="_self">RODRIGUEZ</a></div>
    <div class="fotografia" id="logo3"><a href="index.html" target="_self">fotografía</a></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="header-menu">
   <header>
     <div class="menu_bar">
         <div class="menu-logo">ar</div><a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-diafragma"></span></a>
  </div>
            
  <nav>
   <ul>
             <li class="submenu">
                 <a href="#">portafolio <span class="caret icon-dropdown"></span></a>
                    <ul class="children">
                     <li><a href="spacio.html">Spacio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="rancho.html">Rancho</a></li>
                        <li><a href="new_kid.html">New Kid</a></li>
                        <li><a href="retro.html">Retro</a></li>
                        <li><a href="isolated.html">Isolated</a></li>
                        <li><a href="portugal_vega.html">Portugal Vega</a></li>
                        <li><a href="serena.html">Serena Book</a></li>
                        <li><a href="summertime.html">Summertime</a></li>
                        <li><a href="numb.html">Numb.</a></li>
                        <li><a href="voyager.html">Voyager</a></li>
                        <li><a href="let_it_kill_you.html">Let It Kill You</a></li>
                        <li><a href="street_vision.html">Street Vision</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gamarra.html">Gamarra</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
             <li><a href="info.html">info</a></li>
             <li><a href="promo.html">promo</a></li>
             <li><a href="contacto.html">contacto</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
  </div>
```

Here are the links so you can see the problem:

http://armandorodriguez.pe/info

jsfiddle.net/9fdhefqc/

I've found that if I set portfolio href from '#' to ' ' it won't happen but then the menu won't work correctly on mobile, so that's not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: This question was answered by another user in another question i asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713109/responsive-menu-on-hover-submenu-shows-error . So there's no need for more comments. Closed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because after clicking that button, you somehow add additional css `style="overflow: hidden; display: none;"` to the pop-up submenu. It will forever not showing until you click again to revert the css back to `display: block`.

You can change the js file related to it or just disable it from clicking.

Comment: thank you Qiang, but could you please show me the change in js, cause I don't know java script.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [preventDefault()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) to a click handler for your Portfolio link. As the name suggests, it will prevent the default action for an element, which in this case is following a URL.

```
$(".submenu").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); });
```

<strike>Also, it looks like you might have assigned a click handler to hide and unhide "nav" in menu.js. Maybe you meant for this to be a [hover](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp) handler? In other words, try changing this</strike>

```
$('.bt-menu').click(function(){
        if (contador == 1) {
```

to this

```
$('.bt-menu').hover(function(){
        if (contador == 1) {
```

in menu.js.

Comment: thanks man, but it didn't work. i don't know nothing about java script, i just copy/pasted that part from the tutorial. i tried adding what you suggested but with no results. unless i wrote it in the wrong part of the code... can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: also, from what i learned with the tutorial, it has a click handler for the mobile screen size cause it's a responsive menu. the problem comes with the desktop screen size.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the misunderstanding. preventDefault worked for me [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jaynik/a3mtbr4h/)

Comment: i copied the js but it didn't work. once i click 'portafolio' it won't show the submenu on hover again. thanks anyway man.

Comment: No problem! Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Odd that preventDefault seems to work in the fiddle, but I guess that's just the way web programming goes sometimes. Good luck!

Comment: well actually it kinda works. when i pasted it showed me an error (red marker in line 27) so i changed it. but when i test it with this supposed error it works, but ruins the mobile version. now it doesn't open the menu at all in phone screen size.

Answer (score 0):

inside your js file try this part of code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".submenu").onmouseover(function(){
    $(".children").show();
 }):
$(".submenu").onmouseout(function(){
    $(".children").hide();
 }):

}):
```

Comment: hi nilla, could you please provide a jsfiddle? i'm blind here, as i said in another comment, when it comes to javascript i just copy/paste.

Comment: it worked, but ruined the mobile version. now it won't open the menu when pressing the nav button in phone screen size. any ideas?